# Magento "Cannot save shipment." after clicking on Submit Shipment Button

Tags: magento

We are running Magento store for more than 3 years and this error happened today suddenly.

This error happens in Sales->Order

After adding the Shipping Information (Title and Tracking Number) and checking "Email Copy of Shipment", I try to click on "Submit Shipment" Button.

The page reloads and show the following.

> Cannot save Shipment [RED]
>
> The Shipment has been created [GREEN]

I don't have any clue, **why this showing suddenly**. and I am not able to save shipment for all orders in Magento. Please help me to fix this.

EXCEPTION LOG

> Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100029587' for key 2' in /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXx/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
>   Stack trace:
>
> - ## 0 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXx/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
>
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
> - ## 1 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXx/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300):
>
>   Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
>     -#2 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXx/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479):
>     Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
>     -#3 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXx/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>     Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
>     -#4 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXx/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(394):
>     Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO`sa...', Array)
>     -#5 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXx/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574):
>     Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
>     -#6 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(448):
>     Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('sales_flat_ship...', Array)
>     -#7 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Abstract.php(425):
>     Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment))
>     -#8 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318):
>     Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment))
>     -#9 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(151):
>     Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
>     -#10 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/ShipmentController.php(120):
>     Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
>     -#11 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/ShipmentController.php(225):
>     Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_ShipmentController->_saveShipment(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment))
>     -#12 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420):
>     Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_ShipmentController->saveAction()
>     -#13 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):
>     Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
>     -#14 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176):
>     Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>     -#15 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349):
>     Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>     -#16 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXx/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>     -#17 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXx/httpdocs/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'website')
>     -#18 {main}

Comment: please put system.log and exception.log on your question........ it should  be under your magentoDir>var>log

Comment: Hi Amit Bera, I have added Exception log. I cant see any thing related to shipment in system log

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if [this will help your situation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31262/cannot-save-shipment-error-with-non-sample-orders-1062-duplicate-entry-for). It looks like you've been testing / manipulating loads of orders and there is a duplication in the database.

Hope it helps